# How to find high efficiency ignore comment in Xcode

Tags: xcode4

now I find code snip (command+shift+f) in my project. but I want only find in code. Don't search comment.

[image]

Comment: Xcode's search function is pretty brain-dead (and the later version is a step backwards from the earlier one).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, it is no way... Maybe regxp can, But I can't...